# Is there a way to read the content of an element without automatically skipping to the next element in xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read the content of an element that also has child objects I need to read, but using XmlReader.ReadContentAs will automatically skip to the next element. I'm currently using the XmlReader in c#.

Is there another way to read the content of an element without skipping to the next element?

Comment: First: do you need to use `XmlReader`? It's a low-level streaming API, which is fast but hard to use. If you can, `XDocument` will be a lot easier to use

Comment: I need to keep an eye on performance for this particular application, which is why I chose XmlReader, but I'll have a look if XDocument will be okay.

Comment: If `XDocument` is too slow, see if `XmlSerializer` works for you: that generates code which uses `XmlReader` to deserialize into a set of models, so it's about as fast as calling `XmlReader` directly unless you're doing something *very* specialised

Comment: And to answer your question... If you need to walk into the element's children, then don't call `ReadContentAs`. That method reads all of the element's children in order to produce its return value.